# Are gravitons actually lost to the bulk?

Tags: gravity, string-theory, branes

In the brane world version of superstring/m-theory, the weakness of gravity compared to the other fundamental forces can be explained by gravitons not being confined to
being able to travel in the bulk as they're closed strings.

Does this mean that our brane is "losing" gravitons (and therefore energy) to the bulk? Or that the gravitons are still here, but are also spread out in the other dimensions? Or something else?